# How to get values from current row selected in google sheets using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to extract the values from each column of the currently selected row in google sheets but my code seems to always select the values from the first row of the spreadsheet.

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var active_range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var address1 = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(),2).getValue()
  var address2 = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(),3).getValue()
  var city = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(),4).getValue()
  var state = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(),5).getValue()
```

Comment: Your code should be working. I tried replicating it on my end and it works perfectly fine. Can you share your sheet where this issue happens? Or if possible, can you share more of your code?

Comment: I believe the issue is that you don't understand how an active range works. You need to select the particular range or cell in order to get the desired behavior. This is why active ranges are not recommended except for very special scenarios. I would recommend you to restructure your code to make it work without a lot of human intervention.

Comment: @Marios the goal i am trying to accomplish is a user enters a street address in column 2 of the given row, a call is made to the USPS api and returns the normalized address and fills in the the appropriate cells in that row with data returned from the api call. It all works, except for some reason its always pulling the value from the first row instead of the active row

Comment: @JasonE. see above comment

Comment: Are you using an onEdit trigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var val = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(val);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer